# Unable to initialise Spark

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to initialise spark using pyspark in Spyder (IDE) but always get error. (OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

```
File "<ipython-input-7-86b3963ebca1>", line 3, in <module>
    .appName("test_import")\

  File "/home/fly/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)

  File "/home/fly/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 349, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())

  File "/home/fly/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)

  File "/home/fly/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 187, in _do_init
    self._accumulatorServer = accumulators._start_update_server(auth_token)

  File "/home/fly/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 291, in _start_update_server
    server = AccumulatorServer(("localhost", 0), _UpdateRequestHandler, auth_token)

  File "/home/fly/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 274, in __init__
    SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)

  File "/home/fly/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()

  File "/home/fly/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you aren't able to connect with the spark-master. Go to your `/etc/hosts` file and add this line to it.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. Now it's working. Local host was commented out in my /etc/hosts file edited it and not its working.